# How to remove FCM android push notification result

Tags: php, android, json, web-services

i got this result

```
 {
"multicast_id":4913280949692448120,
"success":1,
"failure":0,
"canonical_ids":0,
"results":[{"message_id":"0:1473389987003950%ab9a0bb6ab9a0bb6"}]
}
```

in JSON format which is going to on android device so i want to remove it by webservice .

How can we remove that result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't receive above result in you android phone, its just the result you got by sending push notification.
The "data" parameter you pass will be the JSON that you'll receive on android.

Answer (score 3):

To remove the result you have to add this line

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
```

after this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    "{  \"to\" : \"" . $token
    . "\",\"priority\":10,\"notification\" : {\"body\" : \""
    . $message . "\",\"title\" : \"" . $title
    . "\",\"icon\" : \"myicon\"},\"data\" : " . json_encode($arr) . "}");
```

and before `curl_exe($ch);`

this will remove the fcm multicast result from your response.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your code

```
        $pushToken = 'Your device token';
        $title= 'Your Title';
        $message= 'Your Message';
        $serverKey= 'Your ServerKey';
        $ch = curl_init("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
        $notification = array('title' => $title, 'text' => $message, "message" => $message);
        $arrayToSend = array('to' => $pushToken, 'notification' => $notification, 'data' => $notification, 'priority' => 'high');
        $json = json_encode($arrayToSend);
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
        $headers[] = 'Authorization: key=' . $serverKey; // key here
        //Setup curl, add headers and post parameters.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        //Send the request
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        //Close request
        curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.